# iOS Animation within DrawRect()

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4

I'm trying to animate CGContext drawings within the drawRect method of a view.

### Code Snippet

```
//Initial Attempt

[UIView animateWithDuration:10
 animations:^{
         CGRect marker = CGRectMake(leftLineX-5.0, yCoord-5.0, 10.0, 10.0);
          CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, _barColor.CGColor);
          CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, _labelColor.CGColor);
          CGContextFillEllipseInRect(c, marker);
          CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(c, marker);
     }];
```

---

```
//Next approach

CGRect marker = CGRectMake(255.0, 255.0, 10.0, 10.0);
UIView * markerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:marker];
[self addSubview:markerView];

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(c, marker);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(c, marker);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(c, marker);

[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
    markerView.alpha = 0.0;
    [markerView setNeedsDisplay];
}];
```

## What I know

I think that because the context is being drawn in the current drawRect view that perhaps the UIView isn't aware of the changes made. What's the best way of approaching this situation? I would like to avoid subclassing if possible.

Comment: Why avoid subclassing? It is the right approach here.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid subclassing is because the positioning of the CGContext items I want to animate are dependent on variables of this view.

Comment: The variables will still be variables of this view if this view is created as a subclass.

Comment: The variables which I use however are modified in the drawRect. So those changes won't carry over to the subclass, correct?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, the correct approach was to subclass here.